# QList initialization via initializer list

Tags: c++, qt

My Hard drive got corrupted and I had to set everything up again.

The Problem is that previously working code is now throwing errors.

```
    QList<QColor> colors = {
    QColor(0, 255, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 200, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 170, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 150, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 130, 255, 255),
};
```

Error:
D:\dev\est_tsd\tests\testgis.cpp:19: error: C2440: ‘initializing’: cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'QList'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I read that Qt supports initializer list with QList now 
(Name of the kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit). What am I missing?

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: DEFINES += Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS can be put into the .pro file to fix the error but this is only a workaround.

Comment: which version of Qt5 you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using copy initialization semantic instead of direct list initialization. You should check if you have in .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

and then use:

```
QList<QColor> colors{
    QColor(0, 255, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 200, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 170, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 150, 255, 255),
    QColor(0, 130, 255, 255)
};
```

Comment: thank a lot for the quick answer but the CONFIG += c++11 is already added to my pro file and it does somehow not work. Using this prompts the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last comma.
It becomes:

```
QList<QColor> colors = {
QColor(0, 255, 255, 255),
QColor(0, 200, 255, 255),
QColor(0, 170, 255, 255),
QColor(0, 150, 255, 255),
QColor(0, 130, 255, 255)};
```